# Generating swagger docs from typescript interfaces

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi

I'm using [swager-jsdoc](https://github.com/Surnet/swagger-jsdoc) to document all the DTOs of the app.

I was wondering is there any way to generate the swagger docs automatically from typescript interfaces.

I have a lot of them in the project and also a lot of mongoose schemas and models. It is getting tedious to keep them in sync. On the other hand I do not want to use the swagger generation tools. I prefer the bottom-up approach.

Cheers

Comment: Found a related question but for [generating mongoose schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962292/generate-mongoose-schemas-from-typescript-interfaces). It'd would be nice to shoot two rabbits with one bullet.

Comment: Found [typegoose](https://github.com/szokodiakos/typegoose). That solves half the problem :D Still searching for the swagger counterpart.

Answer (score 7):

Another option to [tsoa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57479677/1763012) is [routing-controllers](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers) + [routing-controllers-openapi](https://github.com/epiphone/routing-controllers-openapi). The main difference between the two (AFAIK) is that `tsoa` relies on code generation whereas `routing-controllers` operates wholly on runtime. Both methods have their upsides: `tsoa` is able to e.g. utilize richer metadata (such as code comments) whereas with `routing-controllers` we can skip the generation step. My recommendation is to check both out!

One more option is [typescript-json-schema](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema), which generates JSON Schema out of Typescript interfaces; after you have defined your models in JSON Schema you're not terribly far off from an OpenAPI spec.

Comment: Be aware that TSOA currently does not currently support route specific middlewares. Also routing-controllers-openapi does not seem as feature rich as TSOA.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can easily generate Swagger and OpenAPI documents from your TypeScript types by using [tsoa](https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa). The readme contains all of the setup information that you would need to start using it. It's compatible with express, hapi, koa, and more:

https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa

---

(Full Transparency: I ~am~ was one of the maintainers of tsoa. But I was first a consumer of tsoa and I find it to be a great product... that's why I asked to help maintain it! :) ) I’ve since stepped back, but the new maintainers are awesome!

Comment: Why does tsoa not support route specific middleware at the moment. Also is there a workaround for this particular feature?

Comment: That’s a question thats better suited as a github issue as a feature request of tsoa. But the short answer is type safety. Ask the new maintainer of tsoa in their github and you might get a different answer.

Comment: @GreeneCreations can i use tsoa with Lambd Proxy event

Comment: @GowsikKC, I don’t know.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-to-openapi to generate Swagger Schemas From the interfaces.

Example: Considering the User interface bellow:

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  nickname?: string;
}
```

In terminal run the followed command:

```
npx ts-to-openapi -f User.ts -t User >> User.ts
```

After this your interface User will be updates as bellow:

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  nickname?: string;
}

/**
 * @swagger
 * components:
 *   schemas:
 *     User:
 *       additionalProperties: false
 *       properties:
 *         email:
 *           type: string
 *         name:
 *           type: string
 *         nickname:
 *           type: string
 *       required:
 *         - name
 *         - email
 *       type: object
 */
```

Comment: The ts-to-openapipackage is “no longer heavily maintained,” and the project page points to the more active and comprehensive [typeconv](https://github.com/grantila/typeconv/) package which supports more than just ts/openAPI generation